# Compiler errors in xCode 6 final release

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit, xcode6

I was working with a game in swift StriteKit using the beta Xcode. But now with the final release I had a lot of error all of them I been able to fix except this one.

THIS WAS MY ORIGINAL CODE WITH NO ERRORS USING BETA XCODE:

```
bird.zRotation = self.clamp(-1, max: 0.5, value: bird.physicsBody.velocity.dy *     (bird.physicsBody?.velocity.dy < 0 ?0.003 : 0.001 ))
```

But xCode final release indicates a compiler error on physicsBody stating that: 'SKphysicsBody?' does not have a member called velocity. 
I fix this by adding '?' the optional type to physicsBody.

```
bird.zRotation = self.clamp(-1, max: 0.5, value: bird.physicsBody?.velocity.dy *     (bird.physicsBody?.velocity.dy < 0 ?0.003 : 0.001 ))
```

But stil a new error appears this time on dy stating GGFloat not unwrapped I tried using '!' after dy or '?' still the compiler after doing this suggest deleting it, stating Postfix '?' should have optional type ; type is CGFloat.

I have tried to look for information on what is going on exactly but I can't fix this error. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that Xcode is getting confused trying to perform arithmetic on potentially nil values. I'd try moving the optionals out of the `self.clamp` call. Also, watch out for the spacing around the ternary check: it might be trying to unwrap the value adjacent to the `?` operator.

Try

```
if let dy = bird.physicsBody?.velocity.dy {
  self.clamp(-1, max: 0.5, value: dy * ((dy < 0) ? 0.003 : 0.001)
}
```

Comment: Thank you your advice worked. Still trying to fix my original statement but no luck. Thank you